# uib-typeahead is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have implement uib-typeahead for tons of time but i am clueless why it is not working

i want to get item name in the uib-typeahead 
my code here is like this

```
$scope.suggestTestbySpeciality = function( texts , sp_id) {
        var spe_id = sp_id.speciality_id;
$http.post('/youclikc/data/searchTest?speciality_id='+spe_id+'&searchtext='+texts)
                        .then(function(response) {

                        return  response.data.testrecords.rows;

                                                 });
                             };
```

Console.log for function is like this

[image]

Angular is like :

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
<input  type="text"  uib-typeahead="itemz.test_name as itemz.test_name for itemz in suggestTestbySpeciality($viewValue, data1.template_name) | limitTo:8"
 ng-model="templateVo.test_name" placeholder ="Template Test Name"  class="form-control" ></input>
                        </div>
```

Comment: whats present in `response.data.testrecords.rows`

Comment: @Sravan what i am getting in console.log